# Ryzen 7950X3D Hashrate far below benchmark

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, xmrig

I started mining Monero a couple of weeks ago. I hit a dead end in my research and wonder if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

I am running a rig with a Ryzen 9 7950X3D and 128 GB DDR5 RAM in "normal" settings, no overclocking, no changed Voltage or similar, on a Ubuntu 22.04. By these benchmarks I should be able to reach **25ish KHs**: https://xmrig.com/benchmark?cpu=AMD+Ryzen+9+7950X3D+16-Core+Processor.

By iterating through, I think common issues, i.e. huge pages, ports, etc. I got 12.5 KHs with XMR Stak. I switched to XMRig and now I get **18.5KHs**, which is a nice boost. But still so far below the top benchmarks, that I think I am missing something.

I am running 32 threads with the auto-generated CPU setting. No manual settings were able to get better results. All threads sit comfortably at 575 to 590 Hs and have been doing so for days.

I am running p2pool-3.6.2-linux-x64 and xmrig-6.20.0.

It is very telling to me, that I first was stuck at pretty much exactly 50% of the benchmark hashrate with XMR Stak and now at 75% with XMRig. I tried reducing the threads to 16, as I only have that many real cores, but that slows it down massively.

**So concrete question:** Why is XMR Stak so much slower than XMRig and what reason in architecture or setting can it be, that XMR Stak is only managing 50% of benchmark hashrate and XMRig 75% of that?

Answer (score 1):

> So concrete question: Why is XMR Stak so much slower than XMRig and
> what reason in architecture or setting can it be, that XMR Stak is
> only managing 50% of benchmark hashrate and XMRig 75% of that?

Don't use XMR-Stak. The miner that has been kept up-to-date and optimized is **XMRig**.

> I am running 32 threads with the auto-generated CPU setting. No manual
> settings were able to get better results. All threads sit comfortably
> at 575 to 590 Hs and have been doing so for days.
>
> I am running p2pool-3.6.2-linux-x64 and xmrig-6.20.0

You have to also either run as root or manually allocate huge pages, 1gb pages and apply the MSR mods to get the highest hashrate. See https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/randomx-optimization-guide

Also note, the *type* of RAM, timings, and slots installed to will affect hashrate. To edit timings, this can only be edited in the BIOS (things like enabling XMP).